# How can I reactivate the Google API key?

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

We've been sending addresses to Google for a while and then getting the coordinates from Google back and storing them.
This won´t work anymore. 
From Google, we get the following error message:

> You must use an API key to authenticate each request to
>   Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to
>   http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

What must I change in the API settings, so it works again?

Comment: Hello, please introduce yourself to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct your question.

Comment: signup with google, select the google maps api, find the key they assign you and use that in the requests you make

Comment: See the link in [that URL](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/account-changes/), and [get a key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key), then add it to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

You need to add a Billing Account, Maps API is not for free anymore.
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/